# Why not spherical plot? How to plot 3D-polar-plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, polar-coordinates

```
[r,t] = meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,361),linspace(0,pi,361));
[x,y]=pol2cart(sin(t)*cos(r),sin(t)*sin(r));
%[x,y]=pol2cart(r,t);
surf(x,y);
```

[image]

I played with this [addon](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13200) but trying to find an default function to for this. How can I do the 3D-polar-plot?

I am trying to help this guy to vizualise different integrals [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188490/5902).

Comment: @natan I am probably messing up terminology: I want to make it look like circle in 2d and sphere in 3D.

Comment: The current code you added has only 2 coordinates `r` and `t`, so I don't understand where the 3rd dimension should come from... a regular polar plot would do.

Comment: @natan the radius is assumed to be 1. r stands for $\rho$ and $t$ for $\theta$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- You are already converting spherical coordinates to cartesian coordinates with the `sin(theta)*cos(phi)` and `sin(theta)*sin(phi)` bit. Why are you calling `pol2cart` on this (moreover, we're not working in polar coordinates!)?
- As natan points out, there is no third dimension (i.e. `z`) in your plot. For unity radius, `r` can be omitted in the spherical domain, where it is completely defined by `theta` and `phi`, but in the cartesian domain, you have all three `x`, `y` and `z`. The formula for `z` is `z = cos(theta)` (for unit radius).
- You didn't read the documentation for [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html), which says:

  > `surf(Z,C)` plots the height of `Z`, a single-valued function defined over a geometrically rectangular grid, and uses matrix `C`, assumed to be the same size as `Z`, to color the surface.

  In other words, your `surf(x,y)` line merely plots the matrix `x` and colors it using `y` as a colormap.

Here's the above code with the mistakes fixed and plotted correctly:

```
[f,t] = meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,361),linspace(0,pi,361));
x = sin(t)*cos(f);
y = sin(t)*sin(f);
z = cos(t);
surf(x,y,z)
```

[image]